# Htaccess apply page for cms

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I'm trying to code a apply page where you can do /apply/(JOB_ID_HERE) / (RANK_ID_HERE)
Therefore, I need a htaccess file that uses 3 slashes.

Example: http://example.com/apply/1/2

My attemept:

```
RewriteRule ^apply/(.+)$ apply.php?jobid=$1&rankid=$2
```

And I would like to be able to get both variables like this:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['jobid'];
echo $_GET['rankid'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the URL contains two parts that you want to catch. The job ID and the rank ID. But your RewriteRule is clearly only trying to catch one part.

Try this.

```
RewriteRule ^apply/(.+)/(.+)$ apply.php?jobid=$1&rankid=$2
```